# Jquery - On Click on Select Element - How to only execute once each time I click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've a select element on a form and I need that when I click on it that some code executes AND when I choose an option that no code is executed.

The code below is being executed twice so I cannot choose an option, the code executes itself again and I'm left with a reset on the option I choose.

The HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="opportunity_id" name="opportunity_id">
    <option value="">(Choose opportunity)</option>
</select>
```

The JS:

```
$('#opportunity_id').on('click', function(ev) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "/opportunitylist/",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(resOpportunities) {

        var $select = $('#opportunity_id');
        $select.find('option').remove();

        var count = 0;
        $select.append("<option value=''>(Choose opportunity)</option>");
        $.each(eval(resOpportunities), function(key, value) {
            $select.append('<option value=' + value[0] + '>' + value[1] + '</option>');
            count = count+1;                              
        });
      }
    }); 
});
```

My question, there is some fix to this code? How can I get this code executed once each time I click on the select element?

Comment: Use the `change` event instead of `click`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with on focus

```
$('#opportunity_id').on('focus', function(ev) {

$.ajax({
  url: "/opportunitylist/",
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(resOpportunities) {

    var $select = $('#opportunity_id');
    $select.find('option').remove();

    var count = 0;
    $select.append("<option value=''>(Choose opportunity)</option>");
    $.each(eval(resOpportunities), function(key, value) {
        $select.append('<option value=' + value[0] + '>' + value[1] + '</option>');
        count = count+1;                              
    });
  }
}); 
});
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. Why not just load these after page loads? They don't appear to be dependent on any other data in ajax

Comment: Hi, I don't load after the page loads because every time the user clicks os the select box I need to make this ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the event handler whenever the event gets triggered using event chaining like :

```
$('.selector')
        .off('click', '.item')
        .on('click', '.item', function() {
            // code goes here
         })
```

So in your case it will be like :

```
$('#opportunity_id').off('click').on('click',callBackEnd());

function callBackEnd(ev) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "/opportunitylist/",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(resOpportunities) {

        var $select = $('#opportunity_id');
        $select.find('option').remove();

        var count = 0;
        $select.append("<option value=''>(Choose opportunity)</option>");
        $.each(eval(resOpportunities), function(key, value) {
            $select.append('<option value=' + value[0] + '>' + value[1] + '</option>');
            count = count+1;                              
        });
      }
    }); 
}
```